# Convert CSS rule to JavaScript property

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a quick way or predefined JavaScript method that converts

```
"text-align"
"-webkit-transform"
"position"
"background-image"
```

into

```
"textAlign"
"webkitTransform"
"position"
"backgroundImage"
```

with vanilla javascript (no jQuery, ect)?

Comment: Whilst I'm not aware of a method to do so, it should be a fairly trivial job with a regex replace if the rules are assumed to just be "remove initial hyphen if present, and remove subsequent hyphens and capitalise the following letter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting around I found that the variable I was dealing with was of type `CSSStyleDeclaration` which comes with a method [getPropertyCSSValue](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/css/CSSStyleDeclaration.html)

Simplified extract

```
var rules = document.styleSheets[0/*sheetIndex*/].rules[0/*ruleIndex*/];
console.log(rules.toString()); // "[object CSSStyleRule]"
for(var a = 0; a<rules.style.length; a++)
{
  var rule = rules.style[a];
  console.log(rule,rules.style.getPropertyCSSValue(rule).cssText); // eg: "text-align","center"
}
```

This avoids issues with `"border"` and `"border-left"`

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex replace:

```
"text-align".replace(/-([a-z])/g,function(m,l,i){return i?l.toUpperCase():l})
```

It matches a hyphen and then a letter. The replace returns the letter, capitalized if the index is truthy (not 0).

Comment: +1 Couldn't think of a quick way of removing the first hypen without altering the following character

Comment: The accepted answer from @Issac did not work for me in latest Chrome. The conversion rule is as easy as the solution in this answer.